# getopts throwing invalid argument error in linux shell script

Tags: linux, getopts

I am trying to run a shell code with getopts arguments passing at run time. But below script is throwing "Invalid Argument" error.

```
strt_tim=`date`
while getopts dir:day:size: arg; do
case "$arg" in
dir) dirnm="$OPTARG";;
day) dy="$OPTARG";;
siz) sz="$OPTARG";;
*) echo "Invalid arg";;
esac
done
echo
find $dirnm -mtime -$dy -size +$szM -exec ls -lh \
{} \; | awk '{print $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}'

Executing shell script:

sh delutil.sh -dir /path/of/dir/ -day 10 -siz 100
```

Can someone help me on this why the script is failing?

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**getopts** only parses single character arguments. You need to parse `$opt` variable like explained [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial#a_first_example).

If you need long parameters parsing, use the subtly differently named [**getopt**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopt.1.html).

That said, there are a lot of typos in your script: for example `size` should be `siz`.
Also, be careful when you insert variables inline: `$szM` will be interpreted as `variable szM` and not as `variable sz`M. You need to write it as `${sz}M`.